# Bluetooth not working (Ubuntu 14.10, Acer E5-571, Atheros)

Tags: 14.10, bluetooth, acer, atheros

After following through several other Articles about seemingly the same problem I failed repeatedly to pair Bluetooth devices with my Laptop Acer E5-571. The GUI shows Bluetooth tools, but searching for devices, switched to visible, gives no results. Some config information:

`lsusb` outputs:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b469 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0489:e078 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52e Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0781:5151 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Micro Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`hciconfig` outputs:

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 90:48:9A:DA:36:28  ACL MTU: 1022:8  SCO MTU: 183:5
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:1498 acl:0 sco:0 events:77 errors:0
    TX bytes:2067 acl:0 sco:0 commands:76 errors:0
```

`lsmod` outputs:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
uas                    22673  0 
usb_storage            67010  2 uas
hid_generic            12559  0 
usbhid                 53155  0 
ctr                    13193  1 
ccm                    17856  1 
rfcomm                 75066  12 
bnep                   23980  2 
intel_rapl             19196  0 
uvcvideo               86723  0 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14312  0 
intel_powerclamp       19099  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
nls_iso8859_1          12713  2 
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
coretemp               13638  0 
kvm_intel             149984  0 
videobuf2_core         51547  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_common            15715  1 videobuf2_core
joydev                 17587  0 
kvm                   475233  1 kvm_intel
videodev              163831  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
media                  22008  2 uvcvideo,videodev
crct10dif_pclmul       14268  0 
crc32_pclmul           13180  0 
hid_multitouch         17657  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13230  0 
arc4                   12573  2 
acer_wmi               20027  0 
ath9k                 162133  0 
ath9k_common           25638  1 ath9k
snd_hda_codec_realtek    76099  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    69995  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ath9k_hw              460416  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     52670  1 
sparse_keymap          13890  1 acer_wmi
snd_hda_intel          30783  5 
snd_soc_rt5640         93325  0 
aesni_intel           169686  3 
btusb                  32691  0 
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    13323  1 aesni_intel
snd_soc_rl6231         13037  1 snd_soc_rt5640
ath                    29397  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
snd_hda_controller     32234  1 snd_hda_intel
mac80211              697143  1 ath9k
bluetooth             486890  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
snd_soc_core          207596  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_hda_codec         144641  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
cfg80211              520257  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
glue_helper            14095  1 aesni_intel
rtsx_pci_ms            18337  0 
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
memstick               16968  1 rtsx_pci_ms
serio_raw              13483  0 
snd_compress           19395  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hwdep              17709  1 snd_hda_codec
cryptd                 20531  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_pcm_dmaengine      15229  1 snd_soc_core
i915                 1031913  6 
snd_pcm               106273  7 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_midi           13564  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            31197  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                63540  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
parport_pc             32909  0 
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
8250_dw                13474  0 
ppdev                  17711  0 
lp                     17799  0 
snd_timer              30118  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
i2c_hid                19065  0 
mei_me                 19565  0 
snd                    84025  23 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_core,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
drm_kms_helper         99802  1 i915
drm                   323675  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
soc_button_array       12771  0 
hid                   110572  4 i2c_hid,hid_multitouch,hid_generic,usbhid
mei                    88473  1 mei_me
parport                42481  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
shpchp                 37216  0 
dw_dmac                12835  0 
dw_dmac_core           28558  1 dw_dmac
snd_soc_sst_acpi       13007  0 
mac_hid                13275  0 
soundcore              15091  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
video                  20649  2 i915,acer_wmi
i2c_designware_platform    13025  0 
spi_pxa2xx_platform    23256  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13564  1 i915
i2c_designware_core    14990  1 i2c_designware_platform
wmi                    19379  1 acer_wmi
lpc_ich                21176  0 
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         23718  0 
ahci                   34220  3 
r8169                  86907  0 
libahci                32446  1 ahci
rtsx_pci               51162  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
mii                    13981  1 r8169
sdhci_acpi             13502  0 
sdhci                  43929  1 sdhci_acpi
```

`uname -a` outputs:

```
Linux Aspire-E5-571 3.18.0-031800rc3-generic #201411022335 SMP Sun Nov 2 23:36:52 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`dmesg|grep Bluetooth` outputs:

```
[   14.138559] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[   14.138573] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   14.138578] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   14.138579] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   14.138583] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   19.711600] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   19.711603] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   19.711611] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   19.809332] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   19.809342] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   19.809346] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you figured out how to upgrade to a 3.18 kernel, upgrading to 3.19.1 will fix your issue as will the 3.16.0-32 that 14.10 should be able to install with the update manager

Atheros bluetooth does need firmware `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware`

Comment: Upgrading to 3.19.1 did the trick indeed. Thank you very much.